# Get path of template inside Word document created from template

Tags: vba, templates, path, ms-word

I have a word template with macros (*.dotm). I need to know the path where the template was stored in the Word document created from the template.

With `Application.ActiveDocument.FullName` I get the (full) path to the template only when I open the template directly in edit mode. When a document has been created from the document `ActiveDocument` points to the newly created document, so it doesn't give me the path I want.

`Private Sub Document_New()` seems to be fired after the document has been instanciated, so this is to late to get the template path value and there seems to be no event that I can use which fires earlier.

Also tried `ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate` but it only returns a string with the filename and not the full path.

How can I get the full path to the template inside the instantiated document?

Please note that **the template is stored on a webserver** (SharePoint) and **thus `ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.Path` currently returns the path inside the temporary internet files**.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
 Sub FindingTemplateFullPath()

      Dim TemplatePath As String
      Dim TemplateName As String
      Dim TemplateFullPath As String

      TemplatePath = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.Path
      TemplateName = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.Name

      TemplateFullPath = TemplatePath & Application.PathSeparator & TemplateName

 End Sub
```

Comment: Problem is, that "ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.Path" points to the temporary internet files, as the Word template is stored on a Server and opened with a browser. What I need is something like the origin, and not the storage location of downloaded template.

Comment: @Shihan you didnt mention that in your question. Try add something like Excel-web-query as a tag to your question. As far as I know, the template only becomes active once it is on your PC. Sorry cant help more.

Comment: You are right, the question has been edited to state this more clearly (or to state it at all).